nexjts application deployed but broken on deployed server
I am running nextjs 14 application on Render.
I managed to sort out everything and the application builds fine.
Locally it builds perfectly well and works nicely.
The problem I am now running into is the following.
Whichever page I open it seems that it won't load any static assets which sit in .next/ folder.
I have no idea what to do next, I tried almost everything I could think of but since I am new to Next there isn't much that I can think of rather than all the standard stuff.
I've checked if the links are alright and it seems that the folder and link path are corelating.
Additionally it appears it will not load js nor css files for some reason while I can indeed see them sitting in .next/.../ folder properly.
The link to deployed website is here: https://united-media-dashboard.onrender.com
I am not sure what I should even provide here to determine easier why this is happening so here's what I think might be relevatn.
package.json
{
  "name": "unitedmedia-dashboard-watch-statistics",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev:docker": "docker compose up",
    "dev:database": "docker compose up postgres",
    "dev:inspect": "NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' pnpm dev",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node .next/standalone/server.js",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "type-check": "tsc --pretty --noEmit",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --check .",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier --write .",
    "migrate:dev": "prisma migrate dev",
    "migrate:deploy": "prisma migrate deploy",
    "prisma:generate": "prisma generate",
    "prisma:studio": "prisma studio",
    "prisma:seed": "prisma db seed",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@prisma/client": "5.12.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-toast": "^1.1.5",
    "@t3-oss/env-nextjs": "^0.9.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.12",
    "@types/country-flag-icons": "^1.2.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.2",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^3.0.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-crosshair": "^2.0.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^2.0.1",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "country-flag-icons": "^1.5.11",
    "csv-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^3.6.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "lucide-react": "^0.364.0",
    "ms": "^2.1.3",
    "next": "14.1.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-day-picker": "^8.10.0",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.2",
    "sharp": "^0.33.3",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.2",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "tsx": "^4.7.2",
    "zod": "^3.22.4",
    "prisma": "^5.12.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "typescript": "^5.4.3",
    "@types/chartjs-plugin-crosshair": "^1.1.4",
    "@types/ms": "^0.7.34",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.30",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.73",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.23",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.2",
    "prettier": "3.2.5",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^3.2.4",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.13"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "tsx prisma/seed.ts"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx,cjs,json,css,md}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}

next.config.js
import './src/env.js';

/** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */
const config = {
  output: 'standalone',
};
export default config;


It is driving me nuts right now because I have no idea what to do next and docs online have not been helpful much in this case.
Lastly, This is the error I have received in the console - it's referring to the logo and some other assets.
WARNING[GET]404united-media-dashboard.onrender.com/_next/static/chunks/f923c8e2-299bfb92abce4211.jsclientIP="86.32.79.33" requestID="0919b7ec-2317-43e0" responseTimeMS=362 responseBytes=2901 userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
WARNING[GET]404united-media-dashboard.onrender.com/_next/static/chunks/992-a5ed438dcc2c3a39.jsclientIP="86.32.79.33" requestID="2d00e965-6c15-46f8" responseTimeMS=292 responseBytes=1008 userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
WARNING[GET]404united-media-dashboard.onrender.com/_next/static/chunks/app/dashboard/layout-865593bb7b068117.jsclientIP="86.32.79.33" requestID="f80b7d39-0dd9-4683" responseTimeMS=376 responseBytes=3158 userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
INFO[GET]304united-media-dashboard.onrender.com/dashboardclientIP="86.32.79.33" requestID="09b26e22-583f-4298" responseTimeMS=4 responseBytes=0 userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
WARNING[GET]404united-media-dashboard.onrender.com/_next/static/media/6d664cce900333ee-s.p.woff2clientIP="86.32.79.33" requestID="9d16e9bd-0d74-4a5a" responseTimeMS=299 responseBytes=1008 userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
WARNING[GET]404united-media-dashboard.onrender.com/_next/static/chunks/254-13e432276ffed8fc.jsclientIP="86.32.79.33" requestID="b0bbcabf-d7f8-474c" responseTimeMS=298 responseBytes=1008 userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
INFO ⨯ The requested resource isn't a valid image for /_next/static/media/united-logo.e568e235.png received text/html; charset=utf-8

here's also a list of items from shell:
render@srv-coh93qf79t8c73fvc0hg-5d9f8d8765-26csb:~/project/src/.next$ cd static
render@srv-coh93qf79t8c73fvc0hg-5d9f8d8765-26csb:~/project/src/.next/static$ ls
K8DAbg69X2yxP6iIh4nBJ  chunks  css  media
render@srv-coh93qf79t8c73fvc0hg-5d9f8d8765-26csb:~/project/src/.next/static$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-sr-x 6 render render 4096 Apr 20 00:19 .
drwxr-sr-x 7 render render 4096 Apr 20 00:20 ..
drwxr-sr-x 2 render render 4096 Apr 20 00:19 K8DAbg69X2yxP6iIh4nBJ
drwxr-sr-x 4 render render 4096 Apr 20 00:19 chunks
drwxr-sr-x 2 render render 4096 Apr 20 00:19 css
drwxr-sr-x 2 render render 4096 Apr 20 00:19 media
render@srv-coh93qf79t8c73fvc0hg-5d9f8d8765-26csb:~/project/src/.next/static$ cd css
render@srv-coh93qf79t8c73fvc0hg-5d9f8d8765-26csb:~/project/src/.next/static/css$ ls
feeef8ef8e91f5ae.css
render@srv-coh93qf79t8c73fvc0hg-5d9f8d8765-26csb:~/project/src/.next/static/css$ cd ..
render@srv-coh93qf79t8c73fvc0hg-5d9f8d8765-26csb:~/project/src/.next/static$ ls
K8DAbg69X2yxP6iIh4nBJ  chunks  css  media
render@srv-coh93qf79t8c73fvc0hg-5d9f8d8765-26csb:~/project/src/.next/static$ cd chunks/
render@srv-coh93qf79t8c73fvc0hg-5d9f8d8765-26csb:~/project/src/.next/static/chunks$ ls
214.1424e8057e362f8f.js       658-f84f4ecdec402293.js  90234aad-4ae0e29179386fa9.js  framework-c25027af42eb8c45.js  webpack-2fef9b73f9c71af9.js
254-13e432276ffed8fc.js       664-84f0fa31f1da2123.js  992-a5ed438dcc2c3a39.js       main-app-5583196019ffb52a.js
2b07ace6-226c48d4518d6d8e.js  672-c5b93566efc7c0fe.js  app                           main-d8a13b79515d4ca8.js
496-97fa8314988d35b6.js       730-50396ce1a6ab1f06.js  f0cfecc8-081f8fd0371214a0.js  pages
544-4b7d64b4bc18772a.js       770-4b8f34dcd0af2a77.js  f923c8e2-299bfb92abce4211.js  polyfills-c67a75d1b6f99dc8.js
render@srv-coh93qf79t8c73fvc0hg-5d9f8d8765-26csb:~/project/src/.next/static/chunks$ cd ..
render@srv-coh93qf79t8c73fvc0hg-5d9f8d8765-26csb:~/project/src/.next/static$ ls
K8DAbg69X2yxP6iIh4nBJ  chunks  css  media
render@srv-coh93qf79t8c73fvc0hg-5d9f8d8765-26csb:~/project/src/.next/static$ cd media
render@srv-coh93qf79t8c73fvc0hg-5d9f8d8765-26csb:~/project/src/.next/static/media$ ls
162938472036e0a8-s.woff2  4de1fea1a954a5b6-s.p.woff2  6d664cce900333ee-s.p.woff2  f1df658da56627d0-s.woff2  united-logo.e568e235.png

I have tried removing some routes thinking something that I've made caused this behaviour but it did not help, issue remained.
Additionally I have moved some parts I thought could be relevant for the application from devdEpendencies to dependencies.

if you'll have an issue as I did, the solution is to not run the next start with:
"start": "node .next/standalone/server.js",

but instead just run it normally:
    "start": "next start",

it will toss a warning during build:
"next start" does not work with "output: standalone" configuration. Use "node .next/standalone/server.js" instead.

but you can safely ignore it, it will work.
also if you are running into dilemma should you run the standalone server (it runs without node_modules) then you can look at this: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/output#automatically-copying-traced-files
